# Windows 7: Don't download updates while connected with cellular internet

Tags: windows, internet, windows-update, cellular-internet

I want my Windows 7 to install updates without asking me except while it is connected to the internet with a cellular network. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [NetProfiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/) along with a batch script to disable automatic updates when you connect to the specified network. The script would look like this:

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU /v NoAutoUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Then have this script run upon connection to any other network (re-enable automatic updates)

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU /v NoAutoUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Save the first as something like `off.bat` and the second as `on.bat` and configure NetProfiles to run them.